# Something as awesome as ContentProvider but private (not sharing data with other apps)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I really love the concept of 'Loaders', 'ContentProviders' and especially 'ContentObservers'. I use this standard pattern where data is loaded from a local db and when it's updated from my server it's refreshed with `getContentResolver().notifyChange()` or something like this.

But when I use ContentProvider I have to expose my data to other apps. Why is that? I don't have any sensitive data, but it doesn't seem very elegant to me. So did I miss something here, or using ContentProvider (and thus exposing my data) is the only way to implement it easily.

What I really miss from other implementation options is to notify Loaders that new data appeared in local db.

Comment: You missed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814610/android-private-content-provider

Comment: or protect it with your own [`android:permission`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html) if you want to expose it to your apps only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be perfectly clear here: you do *not* have to expose your data to other apps when you use a content provider. Instead, you can use the android:exported="false" attribute in the 
 element in your manifest.

Using permissions to restrict access to a provider (but not prevent it) is described in great detail in [Creating a Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) in the Android API guide.